# Upgrade cassandra 1.0.6 version to cassandra 1.0.7 version

Tags: cassandra

I use Apache Cassandra 1.0.6, but this release seems to have some bugs which were fixed in 1.0.7. One particular bug fix is for a 'too many files' exception. I googled the exception and found out that 1.0.7 release fixes this and that 1.0.7 is more stable than the 1.0.6 release of Cassandra.

How can I upgrade without any loss of data? Is it fine to upgrade from 1.0.6 to 1.0.7?

Comment: 1.0.7 is indeed more stable.
Regarding open files, check also your OS settings.
How did you installed 1.0.6 and what OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra upgrade instructions are always located in NEWS.txt in binary distribution. For version 1.0.7 it says:

```
Upgrading
- Nothing specific to 1.0.7, please report to instruction for 1.0.6
```

So, rolling upgrade of your cluster should be just fine to upgrade from 1.0.6